# MYSQL JOIN query to append data inclusive of both tables even if content doesn't intersect

Tags: mysql, join

Trying to do a JOIN in MYSQL that results in a data set that includes all `Topics` as well as joined data `AppId` & `TopicOrder` where `AppId = 70`

Table 1: Topics

```
Id  |  Topic Name
--------------------
1   |  Inspiration
2   |  Motivation
3   |  Happiness
4   |  Health
5   |  Love
6   |  Career
```

Table 2: AppTopics

```
AppId  |  TopicId  |  TopicOrder
-----------------------------------
70     |  1        |  1
70     |  4        |  2
70     |  6        |  3
50     |  2        |  1
50     |  3        |  2
```

Resulting Goal:

```
Id  |  Topic Name  |  AppId  |  TopicOrder
---------------------------------------------
1   |  Inspiration | 70      |  1
2   |  Motivation  |         |
3   |  Happiness   |         |
4   |  Health      | 70      |  2
5   |  Love        |         |
6   |  Career      | 70      |  3
```

Comment: far easier to do this at database level using a join. Post your tables.

Comment: yeh, tried that too, but can't see how to get ALL topics along with the joined matches for a specific AppId, INNER, LEFT and RIGHT all produce the intersected results only @e4c5

Comment: I thought that's the whole point of asking here :) please post an MCVE, The tables with a few sample rows and the expected output. Let this question be in case someone wants to struggle through php to help you. Post a new question

Comment: Updated per suggestion @e4c5 please let me know if this is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following JOIN will get you the result

```
SELECT * FROM topic LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT * FROM apptopic WHERE apptopic.appId = 70) AS a
   ON topic.id = a.topicId
```

Comment: Bam! Thanks @e4c5

Comment: glad to have been of help